# My modal Bootstrap exist but not visible

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I wrote this code to show up a modal.
when i click on the button and i inspect, my modal exist so i can check my elements, but my modal is invisible.

When i click on the button and i inspect, a style is added to my modal like this  `<div class="modal fade bg-dark in" id="exampleModal" style="display: block;">`

1. I activate popups on chrome
2. I have jquery before bootstrap and visible in my network

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/jquery-ui.css')}}"
</head>
</body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
<div class="modal fade bg-dark" id="exampleModal" >
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
</div>

 <script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
 var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
  var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Inspection look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE0UF.png)

Comment: Have you added the bootsrap.js and jquery.js? I'm not seeing them on your html and both are required for what you are trying to accomplish https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: yes i did , i just removed them in this code

Comment: Try adding model body at the end of your code right after all the scripts and right before <body>, it will be visible.

Comment: @ViperTecPro didnt understand. where exactly please ?

Comment: Take a look at your second "link" tag, it is missing the trailing '>'  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/jquery-ui.css')}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me, change the stylesheets href and scripts src to your convenience

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open
    modal for @getbootstrap</button>
<div class="modal fade bg-dark" id="exampleModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var recipient = button.data('whatever')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button type="button" id="openModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
```

in your `<script>` put this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#openModal').click(function(){
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  )}
)}
```

put this cdn

```
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Same probleme, my modal apprear  but still invisiible. i can check element in the inspection.

Comment: When i click on the button and i inspect, a style is added to my modal like this : <div class="modal fade bg-dark in" id="exampleModal" style="display: block;">

Comment: you have inside the `asset` one folder assets? or `assets/css/boots`

Comment: I have \public\assets  Where there are js and css file

Comment: you add `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: I tried, my files css arent redirected correctly, i need to add assets

Comment: Oui also jquery.js

Comment: put `cdn botstrap.js`

Comment: still the same problem :c

Comment: you need `bootstrap.js` what version bootstrap you use?

Comment: I have my bootstrap.js in my network , i got the latest version.  Do you know why there is style=displat:block  for my modal ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reorder your blade structure,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/jquery-ui.css')}}"
    </head>
    </body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

            <script>
                $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
                    var recipient = button.data('whatever')
                    var modal = $(this)
                    modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
                    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)})
            </script>

            <div class="modal fade bg-dark" id="exampleModal" >
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </body>
    </html>
```

also updating custom class

```
<div class="modal fade bg-dark in" id="exampleModal">
//TO
<div class="modal fade in bg-dark" id="exampleModal">
```

Comment: I still have the same problem !

Comment: Are you sure you followed bootstrap right cuz i didnt see your bootstrap.min.js

Comment: i just removed them in this code code. don't worry.. 
When i click on the button and i inspect, a style is added to my modal like this : 
<div class="modal fade bg-dark in" id="exampleModal" style="display: block;">

Comment: Same problem :c

Comment: can you provide us inspect element console view if its reflecting error ? either you're applying it properly or some cache issue otherwise code seems to working fine

Comment: Yes that looks the problem, maybe you need to reorder it like this ...<div class="modal fade in bg-dark" id="exampleModal" >

Answer (score 0):

Just put your modal code at the end of your code (after the whole resources)  before the 

    
        
            
                 
....
                
                
                ...
                
                .....

Answer (score 0):

For me it resolved when I removed the following:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

And added:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

in my index.html File.